# What does this malware site do? And is Firefox Linux 3.6.7 vulnerable to it?

Tags: firefox, malware, avg-antivirus

Somebody embedded a picture from this site in a post of his in a web forum I frequent. The picture appears normally. When I try to browse to its naked domain name (under "URL" below), I get this warning from AVG Free under Windows XP:

> Danger: AVG Active Surf-Shield has
>   detected active threats on this page
>   and has blocked access for your
>   protection.
>
> The page you are trying to access has
>   been identified as a known exploit,
>   phishing, or social engineering web
>   site and therefore has been blocked
>   for your safety. Without protection,
>   such as that in the AVG Security
>   Toolbar and AVG, your computer is at
>   risk of being compromised, corrupted
>   or having your identity stolen. Please
>   follow one of the suggestions below to
>   continue.
>
> URL: pics DOT blameitonthevoices DOT com
>   Name: Script Injection (type 370)

Am I at risk for having the picture from that site appearing in my browser? The (obfuscated) URL of the pic is "http COLON SLASH SLASH pics DOT blameitonthevoices DOT com SLASH 042010/peta_facts.jpg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Script Injection"

There is a malicious script running on that web page, I suggest you don't go there.

The owner of the website may or may not know it is serving malicious scripts.

Firefox has a add on called No Script, which will block scripts by default.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722/

.

Comment: +1 explanation AND solution ;-) With blocked scripts you should see the picture but the malicious script won´t be running.